# iOS7 safari, event when menu bar hides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

In iOS7, when you scroll down (swipe up) the menu bar on the bottom hides, when you scroll back up, it appears again.

Is there any event send out when this happens?

I have an overlay that fills the entire screen vertically, but when a user scrolls on the page, this overlay doesn't fill anymore due to the menu bar hiding.
I don't want to listen to a scroll event constantly, although for now that seems like the only option.

Comment: can you show the css of the overlay? http://jsfiddle.net/ruLLfpa0/3/

Comment: @Brian, the height is set with javascript, that's why I want to listen to some sort of event. However I might try to do it with CSS, which shouldn't really be a problem if it's possible.